# Как забрать значение с конфига в NgModule > imports

Tags: angular, angular8

app.module:

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { AppConfigService } from './@_shared/app-config/app-config.service';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: //сюда надо забрать значение с конфига
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService) => {
        return () => {
          return appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
        };
      }
    },
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ..
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

для работы с конфигом у меня есть сервис `AppConfigService` и метод Get("").

В обычном сервисе вызываю так :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private appConfigService: AppConfigService
  ) { }

  test(){
    return this.appConfigService.Get("apiBaseUrl");
  }
}
```

А как вызвать в `NgModele` внутри `imports`.... или как организовать по другому?

Comment: Никак. А почему бы тебе просто не захардкодить значение там же? Если оно не изменяется, то есть ли смысл хранить его где-то на стороне сервера? Ключ то все равно вставляется в урл при загрузке - `maps/api/js?key=BLAH_BLAH`

Comment: @overthesanity во первых как быть с гитом? не закидывать этот файл полностью?p s я понимаю что к ключу можно настроить безопасность, но все же не хотелось бы его показывать. Во вторых...хотелось бы вынести это значение в конфиг (веб-морда будет распространятся по лицензии и ставиться отдельному клиенту...естественно у каждого будет разный ключ)

Comment: @overthesanity возможно есть возможность указать сам ключ не в `imports`, а в теле класса где то ?

Comment: обычно такая проблема решается через серверный рендеринг. Если у каждого клиента свой ключ, то конфиг прокидывается в переменные окружения, а потом к нему можно получить доступ через `process.env` и добавить какой-то метатег типа `meta name="gmaps-api-key" content="{{ process.env.API_KEY }}"`. А на клиенте просто взять это `content` свойство `document.querySelector('meta[name=gmaps-api-key]').content`. Если не прибегать к SSR, то каждому твоему клиенту придется вручную получать ключ и сеттить его, я думаю что никто не захочет это делать